# Can a new collaborator see previous commits/histories/logs?

Tags: github

I have been working on a repository of github on my own for 2 years . Now, I'm going to add a new collaborator. Before adding him, my question is whether he will have access to previous commits/histories/logs prior to his arriving.

Is it possible to set this option?

Answer (score 0):

The new collaborator will see the complete commit history, since there is no way to restrict read access to certain branches. Write access can be restricted - this is called "banch protection".